# Why is this grep + sed pipeline not doing what I thought it would do?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I'm using this command here of grep and sed,

```
grep -w 'HN8 .* ATP' topol.top | sed -i 's_0[.]09_0.054_' topol.top
```

In my head, I thought the command is fetch lines that have HN8 and ATP, in those lines, replace 0.09 with 0.054. However, when this happens, Lines with HN7 or HN6 etc, with 0.09 are also getting swapped to 0.054.

Whys that? so I can understand how to just look for the values I require changing.

Comment: If you pass a filename argument to `sed` (or most other commands), it doesn't read from stdin, so `grep` is useless.

Comment: Why do you need to use `grep` in the first place? `sed` allows you to specify a regexp as the address part of the command.

Comment: Remove last `topol.top` from your command.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` can either process named files or stdin, but not both. And the `-i` option can only be used when processing named files. So when you specify filename arguments, stdin is not used.

You should use the regexp as the address part of the `sed` command.

```
sed -i '/HN8 .* ATP/s_0[.]09_0.054_' topol.top
```

Comment: didn't know that, thanks! also shortening down the function aswell.